# sampling an igraph in R

Tags: r, igraph

I have a graph object "g" which has around 10000 nodes and 9362132 edges. I wanted to calculate the edge betweeness but it takes a very long time to do this.

Is there a way around to solve this?

Or is it possible to sample the object "g" say a random 500 every time without replacement and compute the properties?

Answer (score 0):

The `betweenness.estimate` function in `igraph` appears to do what you need. Instead of sampling nodes, you can specify a cutoff path length so that extreme values are not measured. Start with a small cutoff, and gradually increase it to see what is feasible.

---

If you just want to sample a few nodes, and get the betweeness, you can do:

```
g <- random.graph.game(100, 3/10) # Generate a random graph
betweenness(g,sample(V(g),10)) # sample 10 nodes an measure betweeness.
```

Comment: This is one option but I would also like to know how to sample the graph.

Comment: @ nograpes: or should I post that as a separate question?

Comment: Note that `betweenness(g,sample(V(g), 10))` first calculates betweenness for **all** vertices, and then shows only 10 of them.

Comment: @GaborCsardi's comment is very helpful, and also indicates that sampling nodes may not have the expected effect of reducing your computation time. To measure the betweenness on a single node, you still need to evaluate all paths through that node *from all other nodes*. So, really, you haven't saved much computation at all. That is why `betweenness.estimate` works, because it limits how many nodes are in the computation.